# Keep duplicate elements separately

Tags: c++

I have a `std::vector<std::string>` `textLines` that contains a large number of, say city names. I remove the duplicates with:

```
using namespace std;

vector<string>::iterator iter;

sort(textLines.begin(), textLines.end());
iter = unique(textLines.begin(), textLines.end());
```

At this point the duplicate elements are all null (empty) strings at the end of the vector with the same size as before `unique()`.

I remove them with:

```
textLines.resize(distance(textLines.begin(), iter));
```

This works OK but is there a way to keep the removed duplicates? It would be better (for me) if the duplicates were just moved to the end and not replaced by empty strings.

The new end is pointed out by `iter`, returned from `unique()` so there is no problem finding the new end of the vector.

Put another way, I want to know which lines had duplicates and which had not.

Comment: why not use unique over a copy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this very simply without actually changing your logic drastically.
You can store duplicates in another container, that is captured by the comparison predicate passed to `unique()`:

```
vector<string> duplicates;
auto iter = unique(textLines.begin(), textLines.end(), [&duplicates](auto& first, auto& second) -> bool {
    if (first == second)
    {
        duplicates.push_back(second);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Live example: [here](https://ideone.com/VlkKAS).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

You could always write your own function, which is advisable for cases like yours where you have a specific request. Something like:

```
//Define a "bool has(const vector &v, int element)" function before

vector<string> nonDuplicates;
vector<string> duplicates;
for (auto i : textList) {
     if (has(nonDupicates, i)) {
          duplicates.push(i);
     }
     else {
          nonDuplicates.push(i);
     }
}
```

This is not a very elegant, or fast, way to do it, so you can probably find a better way, but if you do do it this way, use a binary search for has(), if you have sorted it

Comment: This doesn't take advantage from the fact that the vector is sorted. Proper implementation should be O(n).

Comment: This is horribly inefficient. First thing, the vector is sorted, second thing - you removed the `std::unique` and implemented poor version of it.

Answer (score 0):

With this solution you need additional memory to store elements count.

```
vector<string>::iterator iter;

vector<string> v{ "a", "b", "a", "t", "a", "g", "t" };
sort(v.begin(), v.end());

// Find number of distinct elements
int count = 1;
auto current = v.cbegin();
for (auto i = v.cbegin() + 1; i < v.cend(); ++i) {
    if (*i != *current) {
        ++count;
        current = i;
    }
}
// Count every entry
vector<int> vCount(count);
auto currentCount = vCount.begin();
++*currentCount;
for (size_t i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    if (v[i] == v[i-1]) ++*currentCount;
    else *++currentCount = 1;
}

iter = unique(v.begin(), v.end());
```